# How to access controller function from ui-grid cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I had a link in cellTemplate, when user clicks on link i need to call a function which is in a controller and i need to pass clicked row item to function.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to Egil's answer,
When you use `controller as` functionality, you can use the approach below:

controller:

```
function myController() {
    var vm = this;
    ......
    vm.gridOptions.appScopeProvider = vm;

    vm.myFunction= function () {
    }
}
```

Then when you reference `grid.appScope` it will refer your controller, not the default `$scope` variable

```
grid.appScope.myFunction();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can reach it through `gridApi.grid.appScope`.

For instance `ng-click="grid.appScope.myControllerFn(row.entity)`

Comment: for me, it was inside `col.grid.appScope`, go figure. But it helped a lot, thanks!